# PHP equivalent ColdFusion ValueList()

Tags: php, coldfusion

I'm learning PHP and was wondering if there some like [ValueList()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/valuelist.html) for PHP? Thank you in advance.

```
$data = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 851099
        [title] => Iron Maiden
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 852099
        [orgName] => Judas Priest
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 861099
        [orgName] => Black Sabbath
    )

)

$valueListTitle = ValueList($data.title)
echo $valueListTitle;
```

which return this: "Iron Maiden, Judas Priest, Black Sabbath"

Comment: Are you switching from CF to PHP or just learning PHP?

Comment: My company is converting all our ColdFusion applications to PHP.

Comment: I wish you luck. I've seen that play out several times; none as well as originally expected. CF is far from perfect, but there will be a lot of things in PHP that you'll appreciate the ease with which CF did it. What kind of data is this? Is it a query result?

Comment: Thanks Shawn, this data is from a query.

Comment: Your structure is not valid. You need to go `array(0 => array('id'=>1, 'title'=>'test title'))` or use the denser syntax in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, check out [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to add commas.

Sample usage:

```
$data = array(
  ["id" =>1, "title"=>"Iron Maiden"], 
  ["id" =>2, "title"=>"Judas Priest"],
  ["id" =>3, "title"=>"Black Sabbath"],
  ["id" =>4, "title"=>"Deep Purple"],
  ["id" =>5, "title"=>"Rolling Stones"]
);

$valueListTitle = array_column($data, 'title');
$commaSeperated = implode(", ", $valueListTitle);
echo $commaSeperated;
```

which return this: "Iron Maiden, Judas Priest, Black Sabbath, Deep Purple, Rolling Stones"

Comment: Hi Nico, I've update the array info.Your suggestion doesn't work with this updated array structure. Any suggestion?

Comment: @user752746 The above is just a dense way of initializing the array. You cannot use the output of `print_r` to initialize the array because `[0] => 'whatever'` doesn't work, you must use `0 => 'whatever'`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php for a bunch of examples.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I got to work the with your suggestion with a little tweaking!